# Django: Determining ManyToMany Relationship in Template

Tags: python, django, filtering, django-templates

I had a `ForeignKey` relationship set up like this:

```
class WatchList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Thing(models.Model)
    watchlist = models.ForeignKey(WatchList, null=True, blank=True)
```

This allowed me to conditionally show different messages in my template like this:

```
{% if thing.watchlist.user != request.user %}
     Something
{% else %}
     Nothing
{% endif %}
```

---

However, now that I have changed my relationship from `ForeignKey` to `ManyToManyField`, this kind of in-template filtering no longer works:

```
class WatchList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Thing(models.Model)
    watchlist = models.ManyToManyField(WatchList)
```

Trying this type of templatetag filtering in the template reveals an `AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'user'`.

How do I filter objects in my template with a ManyToMany relationship so that I can show different messages if `{% if thing.watchlist.user != request.user %}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
{% if thing.watchlist.user != request.user %}
```

by

```
{% if request.user not in thing.watchlist.user.all %}
```

because now you have a m2m relationship so a list of users not just one. 
so the `.all` will return the list of users and not a m2m object (not sure it's an object, don't know how to call it)